# pyspark: Is it possible to create array with missing elements in one struct

Tags: pyspark

My input DataFrame schema is like below. The difference between elements 1 and 2 in d is 1 has attributes a,b,c,d and 2 has only a,b,c

```
root
 |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c: string (nullable = true)
 |-- d: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- d: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
```

I am trying explode the elements of d using below code

```
df2 = inputDF.withColumn("d1",f.explode(f.array("d.*").getField("c")))
```

and getting error pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'array(`d`.`1`, `d`.`2`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function array should all be the same type, but it's [struct<a:string,b:string,c:string,d:double>, struct<a:string,b:string,c:string>];
'Project [a#832, b#833, c#834, d#835, explode(array(d#835.1, d#835.2)[c]) AS d1#843]
+- Relation[a#832,b#833,c#834,d#835] json

**Is there any way to instruct the function to assume NULLS when missing columns in input to array function?**

Comment: Can you provide some input data and show the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

You can explode array of struct where one of the element missing a field as in you case by following:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, ArrayType, StructField, StringType

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("SparkTesting") \
    .getOrCreate()

d_schema = ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField('a', StringType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('b', StringType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('c', StringType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('d', StringType(), nullable=True),
]))
df_schema = (StructType()
             .add("a", StringType(), nullable=True)
             .add("b", StringType(), nullable=True)
             .add("c", StringType(), nullable=True)
             .add("d", d_schema, nullable=True))

item1 = {
    "a": "a1",
    "b": "b1",
    "c": "c1",
    "d": [
        {
            "a": "a1",
            "b": "b1",
            "c": "c1",
            "d": "d1"
        },
        {
            "a": "a1",
            "b": "b1",
            "c": "c1",
        }
    ],
}

df = spark.createDataFrame([item1], schema=df_schema)

df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)

df2 = df.withColumn("d1", f.explode(col("d")))
df2.printSchema()
df2.show(truncate=False)
df2.select("d1.c").show()

+---+---+---+--------------------------------------+------------------+
|a  |b  |c  |d                                     |d1                |
+---+---+---+--------------------------------------+------------------+
|a1 |b1 |c1 |[{a1, b1, c1, d1}, {a1, b1, c1, null}]|{a1, b1, c1, d1}  |
|a1 |b1 |c1 |[{a1, b1, c1, d1}, {a1, b1, c1, null}]|{a1, b1, c1, null}|
+---+---+---+--------------------------------------+------------------+
```

In case you are not sure whether the array field `d` itself will be null then its advisable to use `explode_outer()` function instead of `explode()`.

**As per the comment to match the schema:
below code will work:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("StructuredStreamTesting") \
    .getOrCreate()
d_inter_schema = (StructType([
    StructField('a', StringType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('b', StringType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('c', StringType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('d', StringType(), nullable=True),
]))
d_schema = StructType().add("1", d_inter_schema, nullable=True).add("2", d_inter_schema, nullable=True)

df_schema = (StructType()
             .add("a", StringType(), nullable=True)
             .add("b", StringType(), nullable=True)
             .add("c", StringType(), nullable=True)
             .add("d", d_schema, nullable=True))

item1 = {
    "a": "a1",
    "b": "b1",
    "c": "c1",
    "d": {"1": {
        "a": "a1",
        "b": "b1",
        "c": "c1",
        "d": "d1"
    },
        "2": {
            "a": "a1",
            "b": "b1",
            "c": "c1",
        }
    },
}

df = spark.createDataFrame([item1], schema=df_schema)

df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)

+---+---+---+--------------------------------------+
|a  |b  |c  |d                                     |
+---+---+---+--------------------------------------+
|a1 |b1 |c1 |{{a1, b1, c1, d1}, {a1, b1, c1, null}}|
+---+---+---+--------------------------------------+
df.select("d.1.c", "d.2.c").show()
+---+---+
|  c|  c|
+---+---+
| c1| c1|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Actually in my case my input for column d in  struct format as shown below. If I input like below then its not working `code` item1 = {
    "a": "a1",
    "b": "b1",
    "c": "c1",
    "d": {
        "1": {
            "a": "a1",
            "b": "b1",
            "c": "c1",
            "d": "d1"
        },
        "2": {
            "a": "a1",
            "b": "b1",
            "c": "c1",
        }
    }
}

Comment: @Ram I have updated the answer to match your schema, please let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I gave structure for one sample json. Some times my key names(1,2) are dynamic and in some files it will have 1 element and some times may have 10 elements. Also complete schema is very large . How to handle the dynamic  elements in struct d

Comment: Actually speaking struct d is really a good candidate for array type. Do you have any control on having the source send them as array instead of struct? 

Struct is actually supposed to be static rather than dynamic. You could do a workaround though, define your struct d with what is the maximum elements you expect for example, 10, or 20? and keep each one nullable, so if you dont have all 20, then it will work as normal and at the same time, if you have 20 that also will cover.